# How do I resolve .htaccess conflict with server configuration?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Script installed successfully but after installation when a link is been clicked including login/signup link it shows

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable 
to complete your request.
```

below is my .htaccess setting:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4

 #Options -MultiViews 

 #Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ## Uncomment (remove # ONLY NOT ##) line below if installed in folder and add folder name after /
    ## Example: Script is installed in /public_html/folder/ then it should be: Rewritebase /folder/
    ## Then the files below should be (add slash to all): /index.php?action=$1
    ## Uncomment the code below to Use PHP 5.4
    # AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

    RewriteEngine On

    ## Uncomment the following line to use the multi-domain feature
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourseconddomain\.com$ [NC]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourfirstdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    #Rewritebase /
    ## Admin Panel
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ admin/index.php?a=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    ## Application Handler
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?a=$1  [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>

## Error 404 ##
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?a=404
```

**NOTE**: I don't have access to apache my website is installed on 1and1.com

Comment: have you checked server error log? I guess config option is limited by your hosting provider.

Comment: When I checked now my error log is deactivated